# Using data from SQL Server and Oracle

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on getting my application to use data from both a SQL Server database and an Oracle database. I have a `DbContext` class for each one with a corresponding `DbConfiguration` class.

SQL Server:

```
public class SqlDbConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public SqlDbConfig()
    {
        this.SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory());
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(SqlDbConfig))]
public partial class VcisAppContext : DbContext
{
    public VcisAppContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    { }
 }
```

Oracle:

```
public class OracleDbConfig : DbConfiguration
{
    public OracleDbConfig()
    {
           SetDefaultConnectionFactory(new OracleConnectionFactory());
           SetProviderServices("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",    EFOracleProviderServices.Instance);            
           SetProviderFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client", new OracleClientFactory());
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(OracleDbConfig))]
public partial class VcisDataStoreContext : DbContext
{
        // first try
        // public VcisDataStoreContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(new OracleConnection(nameOrConnectionString), true) { }
        // second try
        // public VcisDataStoreContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString) { }
        //let's try passing a connection 
        public VcisDataStoreContext(DbConnection dbConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(dbConnection, contextOwnsConnection) { }
```

Adapter Code:

```
public FundAdapter(IOptions<AppSettings> appOptions)
{
        //Create a connection and pass it in
        var connection = new OracleConnection(appOptions.Value.VcisDataStoreConnection);

        var context = new VcisDataStoreContext(connection, true);
        // try passing in a connection string
        //var context = new VcisDataStoreContext(appOptions.Value.VcisDataStoreConnection);
        this.repository = new FundRepository(context);
        this.mapper = Mapper.Instance;
}
```

When the SQL Server `DbContext` is used first it works and the Oracle `DbContext` fails. If I don't call the SQL Server `DbContext` first, the Oracle one works.

Is it possible to use both SQL Server and Oracle together in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Update: The error message I see is:

> Unable to determine the provider name for provider factory of type 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory'. Make sure that the ADO.NET provider is installed or registered in the application config.

When I look at the context object in the debugger the `context.Database.DefaultConnection` is showing:

```
Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
```

So even with passing the correct Oracle connection the Context object still has the wrong `DbFactory`.

Comment: What do you mean by "fails"?  Do you get an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: See my post here for the answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2434fe10-3219-4625-bdbf-b9e96421230b/entity-framework-with-oracle-and-sql?forum=adodotnetentityframework